# Way to avoid CoffeeScript passing object reference style

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to copy (deep copy specifically) an object in CoffeeScript. Here's the problem:

```
class Mat
  constructor: ->
    @m00 = 5
    @m01 = 3
  mul: (b) ->
    x1 = @m00
    @m00 = x1 * b.m00
    @m01 = x1 * b.m00

x = new Mat
x.mul(x)
alert x.m00 #25
alert x.m01 #125
```

So as you can see,

- x1 gets set to @m00
- @m00 changes
- x1 changes with changes made to @m00

How can I instead get the copy to be a new object with the values so that changing the instance's values won't affect it? I am trying to avoid this...

```
x1 = @m00
y1 = b.m00
@m00 = x1 * y1
```

EDIT:
Another example

```
  @m00 = b.m00 * copy.m00 + b.m01 * copy.m03 + b.m02 * copy.m06
  @m01 = b.m00 * copy.m01 + b.m01 * copy.m04 + b.m02 * copy.m07
  @m02 = b.m00 * copy.m02 + b.m01 * copy.m05 + b.m02 * copy.m08
  @m03 = b.m03 * copy.m00 + b.m04 * copy.m03 + b.m05 * copy.m06
  @m04 = b.m03 * copy.m01 + b.m04 * copy.m04 + b.m05 * copy.m07
  @m05 = b.m03 * copy.m02 + b.m04 * copy.m05 + b.m05 * copy.m08
  @m06 = b.m06 * copy.m00 + b.m07 * copy.m03 + b.m08 * copy.m06
  @m07 = b.m06 * copy.m01 + b.m07 * copy.m04 + b.m08 * copy.m07
  @m08 = b.m06 * copy.m02 + b.m07 * copy.m05 + b.m08 * copy.m08
```

Comment: I don't understand - what is the `mul` function supposed to do? If it's supposed to change the object itself, why do you need a copy at all? If it's supposed to *return* a new instance, why does the function update `@m00` and `@m01` instead of `copy.m00` and `copy.m01`?

Comment: Also in my opinion the "copy" function should not take a parameter - it should be a function that returns a copy of `this` - it's weird to have a function on every instance that takes an argument of what object to copy.

Comment: The `mul` function was just a demonstration. It's not in use. I posted what the real `mul` function does. For clarification, I am attempting to modify the values of the instance with previous values of that instance. So in this case, I would need a copy so that I can make changes while using the previous values, right?

Comment: And to your second point, the goal of copy was to make an object with matching values, but have them separate so that they could change without changing the `this` instance. If that makes sense

Comment: Well I still don't get it. The statement `x.copy(x)` makes a copy but doesn't save the result anywhere; it therefore really doesn't do anything. You then pass "x" into `.mul()` which *changes* "x".

Comment: That was a typo, I apologize. I removed it from the code segment. In the new code, it (hopefully) shows how I am trying to take x1 and keep it as the value of `@m00` without allowing it to change with changes to `@m00`

Comment: I'm with @Pointy - really unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. It looks like some sort of Fibonacci sequence etc. If so, I think you can do it better. If you just want to deep copy an object I'd use `lodash` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you're up to, but let's look at what the latest version of "mul" does:

```
  mul: (b) ->
    x1 = @m00
    @m00 = x1 * b.m00
    @m01 = x1 * b.m00
```

Your code calls "mul" with "x" as both the context and the parameter ("b").  Thus, the first line of code,

```
    x1 = @m00
```

sets local variable "x1" to `x.m00`. That's the same as `b.m00`, remember.

The next line of code sets `x.m00` to the product of the value of "x1" times `b.m00`, which if of course the same as `x.m00`. Thus, after

```
    @m00 = x1 * b.m00
```

the value of `x.m00` (and, because "b" and "x" refer to the same object, `b.m00`) is `25`.

The next statement:

```
    @m01 = x1 * b.m00
```

sets `x.m01` (and `b.m01`) to the product of "x1" and the current value of `b.m00`. Well, "x1" is still `5`, because it hasn't been changed. But `b.m00` is now `25` because of the previous statement. Thus, the value of `x.m01` is set to `125` (`5 * 25`).